# How to add windows 8 boot entry to Grub2?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

How to add windows 8 boot entry to Grub2?

I had windows 7 installed on my primary(and active) partition and windows 8 installed on partition 2 which is logical and not active.
Now I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my primary partition by formatting it to ext3 file format.
The installation succeeded and ubuntu is running fine. 
But now the problem is it doesn't shows any Grub menu to boot Windows.
I tried to reinstall windows to primary partition but the installer(windows 8 installation DVD) is not recognizing the file format of primary partition.
Even "bootrec.exe /fixboot" command is not working because the primary partition is now ext3.

Please tell a way to dual-boot windows and ubuntu or install back windows to primary partition.

Comment: If you have multiple Windows installs there is only one active (boot flag) primary partition. All Windows boot files from all installs will be in that one partition and grub can only find boot files from that one partition. You have to have Windows in a primary partition and move boot flag to it and run repairs to have boot files in it for grub2's os-prober to find it and add a boot entry. May be best to post link to BootInfo report from Boot-Repair. You also must make sure fast boot or always on hibernation is off in Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to use `boot-repair` to reconfigure Windows to the `GRUB`. With that being said, try to follow these instructions provided. In `Ubuntu`, open a `terminal` and type this in:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Once this is done, `boot-repair` will open up. Follow these remaining steps under Recommended Repair:

Recommended repair

```
launch Boot-Repair from either :
    the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)

    or System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)
    or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal 

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.
If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.
```